# Double Integral Question on unit square

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Hints on solving following double integral will be appreciated.

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \text{d}y \ \text{d}x$$

Comment: actually it'll not help if i'm not wrong. $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{1/\cos \theta} \frac{\cos 2 \theta}{r}  \text{d}r \ \text{d}\theta$$ how to solve this?

Comment: Does this even converge?  I sense a non-integrable singularity at the origin.

Comment: Indeed this does not converge (try to estimate the function on the subdomain $y\lt x/2$).

Comment: I gave it to Mathematica. It converges and answer is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the integrand has a non-integrable singularity at the origin, we must evaluate it by iterated integration. So let's consider the inner integral first:

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\, dy &= \frac{1}{x}\int_0^{1/x} \frac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}\, dt \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (y = x\cdot t)\\
&= \frac{1}{2x} \int_0^{2\arctan(1/x)} \frac{1 - \tan^2 (\varphi/2)}{(1+\tan^2(\varphi/2))^2}(1+\tan^2(\varphi/2))\, d\varphi\quad (t = \tan (\varphi/2))\\
&= \frac{1}{2x} \int_0^{2\arctan(1/x)} \frac{\cos^2(\varphi/2) - \sin^2(\varphi/2)}{\cos^2(\varphi/2)+\sin^2(\varphi/2)}\, d\varphi\\
&= \frac{1}{2x} \int_0^{2\arctan(1/x)} \cos\varphi\,d\varphi\\
&= \frac{1}{2x} \sin \left(2\arctan(1/x)\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{x} \sin \left(\arctan(1/x)\right)\cos\left(\arctan(1/x)\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{x} \frac{1/x}{\sqrt{1+1/x^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+1/x^2}}\\
&= \frac{1}{1+x^2}
\end{align}$$

From the on, it's very simple,

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \arctan 1 = \frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Note that the other order of integration,

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\, dx\,dy$$

leads to the value $-\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

The integral does not converge. By various tricks, you can cause some kind of iterated calculation to give any value you like.

You can cut up the domain into parts. For $x^2 + y^2 \geq 1$ there is no trouble. Furthermore, there is a $\pm$ symmetry across the $45^\circ$ line $y=x.$ So, we consider the part $$ x^2 + y^2 \leq 1, \; \; y \leq x. $$ On this part, the integral is, indeed, $$ \int_0^{\pi/4}  \int_0^{1} \frac{\cos 2 \theta}{r} dr d\theta = \frac{1}{2 }  \int_0^{1} \frac{1}{r} dr = \left.\frac{1}{2 } \log r \; \right\rvert_{r=0}^{r=1} $$ which does not work.

There is surely some good way to write the traditional vertical bar symbol denoting the evaluation step for a one-variable integral. I think it will work if I make the $r$ values into an array with a blank line or two in the middle. That's better, array, with matching \left|  and \right. which produces nothing as the right delimiter; if I had put \right| there would be a second vertical bar.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral#Multiple_improper_integral

Comment: I didn't like your array approach. I think it more natural to view the bar as being the right delimiter, where the left delimiter is implicit/invisible. I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Just split the integral as

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \text{d}y \ \text{d}x
=  \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \text{d}y \ \text{d}x
- \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \text{d}y \ \text{d}x. $$

Now, just use standard integration techniques to evaluate the integrals. For instance

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dy=\frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2} + \frac{\arctan(y/x))}{2x}\Big|_{0}^{1} =\dots.  $$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{x^{2} - y^{2}}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}}
&=
{x^{2} + y^{2} -2y^{2} \over \left(x^{2} + y^{2}\right)^{2}}
=
{1 \over \left(x^{2} + y^{2}\right)^{2}}\,\left\lbrack%
{\partial y \over \partial y}\,\left(x^{2} + y^{2}\right)
-
{\partial\left(x^{2} + y^{2}\right) \over \partial y}\,y
\right\rbrack
\\[3mm]&=
{\partial \over \partial y}\left(y \over x^{2} + y^{2}\right)\,,
\qquad\qquad
\left(x, y\right) \not= \left(0, 0\right)
\\[5mm]&
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\int_\epsilon^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \text{d}y \ \text{d}x
&=
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\left.{y \over x^{2} + y^{2}}\right\vert_{\,y\ =\ 0}^{\,y\ =\ 1}\
{\rm d}x
=
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{{\rm d}x \over x^{2} + 1}
\\[3mm]&=
\arctan\left(1\right)
=
{\large{\pi \over 4}}
\end{align}

It seems to be the Mathematica package trick !!!: It's is equivalent to exclude $\left\lbrace \left(0,y\right)\ \ni\ y \in \left(0, 1\right) \right\rbrace$ and takes a limit after integration. It's like this:

\begin{align}
\int_{\epsilon}^{1}
\left.{y \over x^{2} + y^{2}}\right\vert_{\,y\ =\ 0}^{\,y\ =\ 1}\ {\rm d}x
=
\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{1 \over x^{2} + 1}\,{\rm d}x
=
{\pi \over 4} - \arctan\left(\epsilon\right) \to {\pi \over 4}
\end{align}

If you "exclude" both $x = 0$ and $y = 0$ you get:
$$
{\pi \over 4} - \arctan\left(\epsilon\right)-
\arctan\left(1 \over \epsilon\right) + \arctan\left(1\right) \to 0
$$
which is quite obvious ( the integral changes sign when $x \leftrightarrow y$ ).
The problem is related to the singular behavior of the 2D-Green function  of the Laplacian operator:
$\left.\nabla^{2}\ln\left(\rho\right)\right\vert_{\rho\ \not=\ 0} = 0$ but its integral around $\vec{\rho} = \vec{0}$ is $\not= 0$.
$\rho \equiv x\,\hat{x} + y\,\hat{y}$. It's common in 2D-Electrostatic.

For example

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \text{d}y \ \text{d}x
&=
\int_{S}\nabla\times\left({y \over x^{2} + y^{2}}\,\hat{x}\right)\cdot\hat{z}\,
{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y
=
\oint\left({y \over x^{2} + y^{2}}\,\hat{x}\right)\cdot{\rm d}\vec{\rho}
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{1}^{0}{1 \over x^{2} + 1}\,\left(-{\rm d}x\right)
=
{\large{\pi \over 4}}
\end{align}

Answer (score -2):

0 by symmetry.Integrand changes sign across the diagonal

Comment: I voted against deleting this, but that may have been an error. Sorry. You should probably retract this answer.

Comment: this answer is wrong